# R: how to make plots for every rowname

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I got a dataframe that looks like this.
I want to plot for EACH "localidad" the year-mean "rinde" value for the three different "agua_inicial" options. Let´s suppose I have 14 different "LOCALIDAD", then at the end I would like to get 14 different plots (X=year, Y= "rinde") and each plots needs to show me three different curves (for the three different agua_inicial options: high, low, mid).

Im trying to find the way to build this code but it is really difficult

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many approaches come into consideration. Just to name a few:

#### Using ggplot2

Faceting would do exactly what you are looking for. See: https://ggplot2-book.org/facet.html

#### More general, group by with dplyr

It would also be possible to transform the data by oneself and to call the plotting function once for every group. For example:

```
data %>%
  group_by(localidad) %>% 
  group_walk(function(x, y) {
    # The subset of the data is in y.
  })
```

#### With only base functions

```
# Find the different values of localidad:
localidad_values <- unique(data$localidad)

# Iterate through the different values
for (localidad in localidad_values) {
  # Filter the data for only rows with the current localidad
  subdata <- data[data$localidad == localidad,]
  
  # Plot subdata
}
```

I hope this answers your question. Please let me know if you have further questions or if I misunderstood something!

Comment: That was really helpful!! Thank you very much. Now I have a new dataframe called "subdata" for each "localidad", which is the thing I was looking for. Now I am trying to make the different averages Im looking for (before ploting).         The "subdata" dataframe has a column called "agua_inicial (low,mid and high)" and another one called "zafra (these are years from 1961 to 2017)", is there any way to AVERAGE the "agua_inicial" by year? My goal is to have only THREE "agua_inicial" values (low, mid and high) for EACH year. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: I would recommend using tidyverse which contains useful functions for grouping and aggregating. May I point you to the following website https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html ? Otherwise, you could, for example, create a `subsubdata`-dataframe for every year similar to the code above.